# How to update the Daylight saving on my windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

i live in Egypt and our clock is changed again after cancellation of daylight from the government they have returned to set it as daylight saving but my computer doesn't show the check box of daylight saving how to update

Answer (score 0):

Click on Change Time Zone and you will see the check box for Automatically adjust daylight saving time.
Incidentally in Windows 7 if it is of any use you can set an additional two clocks with different time zones.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: If they cancel daylight savings, why would he needs 2 clocks?